# I want to return a record based on the condition

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute a simple if else query based on mysql

```
SELECT IF EXISTS (SELECT nickname FROM contacts WHERE contacts.user_id = 47 AND contacts.contact_id = 69)
BEGIN
    SELECT nickname FROM contacts WHERE contacts.user_id = 47 AND contacts.contact_id = 69
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT CONCAT(users.firstname," ",users.lastname) AS nickname FROM users WHERE users.id = 69
END
```

But it's giving me an error

> Error Code: 1064

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXISTS (SELECT nickname FROM contacts WHERE contacts.user_id = 47 AND contacts.c' at line 1

Can anyone guide me what's the issue here?

Comment: The code is much closer to sqlserver than mysql - where did you get it from? if..then..else..endif and begin..end are only available in stored programs in mysql - is your code in a procedure/function/trigger or event?

Comment: @P.Salmon I got it online from one of the answers. Can we convert it to IF then else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use control flow statements, like `IF`, in queries.

However you can achieve what you apparently want to do with a `UNION ALL` of two queries, one of them returning the empty set depending on your condition.

```
SELECT nickname
       FROM contacts
       WHERE contacts.user_id = 47
             AND contacts.contact_id = 69
UNION ALL
SELECT concat(users.firstname, ' ', users.lastname) nickname
       FROM users
       WHERE users.id = 69
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM contacts
                                    WHERE contacts.user_id = 47
                                          AND contacts.contact_id = 69);
```

Also don't use double quotes for string literals. Yes, MySQL does accept that but in standard SQL single quotes are meant for that job. And it doesn't harm to get used to that and produce more portable code.